# how to make a generic path for a log file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging

Here I am creating the logs folder under the current path of the directory using  Dir::pwd. But I want to change this to pick the directory path from config files which will run in any other machines.

```
date_directory= "#{Dir::pwd}/logs/#{DateHelper.getDirectoryYearStamp}/#{DateHelper.getDirectoryMonthStamp}/#{DateHelper.getDirectoryDateStamp}/"
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(date_directory) unless Dir.exists?(date_directory)
```

I tired with giving the absolute path and it works. But how do I make the directory by passing the relative path?

Comment: Relative to what? To current place? So just 'logs/...' or './logs/...'

Comment: instead of Dir::pwd which will be the current working directory path , i would like to get the user input of the path direcotry..

Comment: So, you need to walk through users' directories, read there config files, find in them string with path and mkdir those paths. Right? Actually it isn't hard :)

Answer (score 0):

You are allready using a relative path, so is is generic solution, the subfolder of your current folder is a relative position. Is the code you published working ? But inside your question you mention config files, is it that what you want ? What kind of file ? a yaml, ini or of a simple text file ?
If a simple textfile you can do with

```
path = File.read("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/path.txt")
```

EDIT: based on your comment, the following snippets wil create a logfile a day in the /some/x/y/z
folder.

```
require 'logger'

$log = Logger.new("/some/x/y/z/logs.txt", 'daily' )
$log.info "teststring"
```

gives in the file "C:\some\x\y\z\logs.txt"

```
# Logfile created on 2013-04-05 13:17:27 +0200 by logger.rb/31641
I, [2013-04-05T13:20:19.811837 #3300]  INFO -- : teststring
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. See i want to pick some pathlike $path='some/x/y/z' and then create the directory under this path.. so without giving the root path like  $path='C:/some/x/y/z' .